# How can I identify an SMD diode marked SX DG?

Tags: diodes, identification

[image]

My question is based on the attached picture of a diode which says SX DG but I can not find this diode.
The diode is taken from PoE 63v part of IP camera attached with MB6s ke47[image]

SXDG SX DG

Comment: on diode SX DG are written

Answer (score 0):

Maybe? :SMBJ58CA littlefuse transint supressor diode in DO-214AA package.

You should specify where did you take those elements from. What is their theoretical purpose.

Comment: Not likely. [SMBJ XXX C A](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) diodes have a cathode band and a Littelfuse logo on them.

Comment: @Huisman bi-directional wouldn't have a cathode band, It could any other manufacturer making equivalent.

Comment: looks like taken out from right side of PCBA